# Azure Functions on linux - No always on available so possible idle app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

We are not used to Linux function apps on Azure but this time we need to run the code on a Linux OS.

I have noticed that there is no "Always on" option on configuration, unlike windows functions where you can turn this option on to prevent inactivity (idle). We also face an issue where our Linux function triggers but the execution stops suddenly sometimes and leaves no log.

**Can the Linux function app go into an idle mode? Or at least some other services related to the function?**

Some images to illustrate the question :

(linux)
[image]

(windows)
[image]

Notice the the "Prevent your app from bein idled out due to inactivity"

Thank you

Comment: Which plan type are you using with your linux functions? "Always On" is independent of the OS. It is an option you will only see on  an app service plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan#always-on

Comment: Thank you @ManuelBatsching we use an App Service plan, and it's not available.

Comment: Even with Always On enabled, the execution timeout for individual functions is controlled by the functionTimeout setting in the host.json project file.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Comment: @MadhurajVadde-MT that time out its here to define de maximum time a function will run. Not at what time the function runs... And my question is about always-on that prevents the function from bein in sleep mode if its not executed for a long time.

Comment: What is the App Service plan for the Function ?

Comment: Azure Portal -> App Service Plans -> Select your app Service plan ->Select the app (from Apps under Settings) -> In App blade, click configuration (under settings section) -> switch to General Settings Tab. You should be seeing option of Always ON

Comment: Please read my question @MadhurajVadde-MT It is not available for a Linux function

Comment: I just created a Function app with OS = "Linux" and Plan Type = "App Service Plan". I followed the above steps and I can see "General Settings" tab along with "Application Settings" and "Function runtime Settings". So suggesting the same

Comment: Yes, but do you see Always-on? @MadhurajVadde-MT It's the main purpose of my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235660/discussion-between-madhurajvadde-mt-and-borisd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the App Service plan to higher (probably P1v2)